# Как разместить текст ровно под фото

Tags: html

Как разместить текст ровно под фото

Comment: Что значит «ровно» и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: @andreymal, "ровно" значит что ничего никуда съезжать не должно и, скорее всего, что явно прописанных размеров быть не должно по крайней мере у текста.

Comment: @Qwertiy под такое описание вполне подходит самый обычный `<img/><br/>Текст` без каких-либо стилей. И что-то у меня такое подозрение, что автора интересует немного не это

Comment: @andreymal, без стилей не отцентрируется. Ладно, я второй вариант придумал - "по ширине изображения". Но первый мне по-прежнему нравится больше.

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=128&d=identicon">
Qwertiy
```

Answer (score 1):

Если имелось в виду по ширине изображения, то так (если позволяет поддержка браузерами):

```css
body {
  width: min-content;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
}

div {
  word-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=128&d=identicon">
Какой-то текст
```